# Event listener callback does not fire via a normal function call

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm sure there's a reasonable explanation for this, but I cannot figure it out - a bit of guidance would be much appreciated.

I have the following code using Backbone:

```
var ExampleCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    exampleEvent: function() {console.log('event fired')}
});

var ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'body',
    onExampleEvent: function() {console.log('listener heard it')},
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection,'exampleEvent',this.onExampleEvent);
    }
});

var testCollection = new ExampleCollection;
var testView = new ExampleView({collection:testCollection});
```

In the console, when I enter the command `testCollection.trigger('exampleEvent')` the `onExampleEvent` callback function fires . however, when I enter the command `testCollection.exampleEvent()` the `exampleEvent` function fires but the `onExampleEvent` callback function doesn't.

If anyone could explain to my why this happens I would appreciate it as I have been looking for a while and can't figure it out.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just think about it - when You call

```
 testCollection.exampleEvent()
```

You just execute it, and... Nothing. When

```
 testCollection.trigger('exampleEvent')
```

is called, it execute function and every listener.

Comment: So are you saying listeners are only called when you call the event via collection.trigger, not anytime the event function is executed?

Comment: Yes. Internals of `.trigger()` call listeners.